# Authentication to access SFTP service using LDAP/KeyClock

Tags: sftp, authentication, kubernetes

My SFTP server is running in K8S pod.I have created service and ingress to access SFTP service from remote.Till this point it is working as expected.I am trying to setup authentication to access SFTP service by integrating LDAP server using SSSD.In logs I can see that SSSD service is starting successfully but when I try to connect from winscp and other clients it authentication is not working.I can see request hitting LDAP server but authentication is not working.Below is sssd config.

```
[sssd]
domains = abc.se
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam,ssh
 
#domains = abc.se
#default_domain_suffix = abc.se
 
[ssh]
 
[domain/abc.se]
id_provider = ldap
access_provider = simple
#ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_search_base = dc=abc,dc=se
#ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
#ldap_tls_reqcert = allow
ldap_uri = ldap://abc.se:389/
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=xyz,OU=CA,OU=SvcAccount,OU=P001,OU=ID,OU=Data,DC=abc,DC=se
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = xxxxxxx
krb5_realm = abc.se
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
entry_cache_timeout = 0
enumerate = True
ldap_user_search_base = OU=User,OU=P001,OU=ID,OU=Data,DC=ericsson,DC=se
ldap_group_search_base = OU=IDM,OU=P001,OU=GRP,OU=Data,DC=ericsson,DC=se
ldap_user_name = uid
ldap_user_home_directory = homeDirectory
ldap_user_object_class = posixAccount
#ldap_user_object_class = ipaSshUser
ldap_group_object_class = posixGroup
ldap_group_member = memberUid
 
[pam]
offline_credentials_expiration = 2
offline_failed_login_attempts = 3
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_failed_login_delay = 5
 
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
```

Here am using ldap port 389 which works without encryption.
I have tried solution explain in blog : https://therubyist.org/2020/04/03/ldap-in-containers.
But this solution also didn't work from me.
Please suggest good way to how I can authenticate my SFTP server using LDAP server.If it is not possible with LDAP can I use keyclock somehow.